# IdentityServer3 error "There is an error determining which application you are signing into. Return to the application and try again."

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver3

I've just started SPA using auralia, with the OAuth login. I willing to use  IdentityServer3 for that purpose and it seems pretty nice, everything works fine on Visual Studio , but when  move the IdentityServer to IIS 7.5 it start to giving  the above error

""There is an error determining which application you are signing into. Return to the application and try again."

any suggestions, where it goes wrong  ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please also see my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44675446/identity-server-3-with-edge-and-ie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means your `Client` configuration in Identity Server does not match the details being provided in the login request.

For this scenario, check that is the `RedirectUri` matches within Identity Server and your Aurelia application, and that this uri is actually being used by the application.

Comment: looks it's related with authorizationEndpoint in configuration , issue is  when we are running Identity Server not in the default port..................... ex: authorizationEndpoint :'http://[ip of the server]:[port]/connect/authorize',    , without issue it reach there... and next page it redirect it to https:/[ip of the server]/login?signin=[guid].. and it missed the port we initially added ..

Comment: So the move to IIS causes Identity Server to strip the port number upon redirect to the login page? What's your situation on SSL? https throughout?

Comment: yes , if we added default port ( 80 in normal or 443 with https) it works.

Comment: #Scott Brady ... sorry my bad , looks we make some mistake and overwrite 'PublicOrigin' property inside the project , which always use to redirect, according to the  documentation (PublicOrigin
By default, IdentityServer uses the host, protocol, and port from the HTTP request when creating links. This might not be accurate in reverse proxy or load-balancing situations. You can override the origin used for link generation using this property.  )