# Identity Server 3 with Edge and IE

Tags: microsoft-edge, identityserver3

I'm going to ask this question and answer it so that it helps others that might run into the problem. I am running Identity Server 3 alongside my main web application (ASP.NET Web Forms) with implicit flow. During development I used the following addresses:

- 192.168.1.100 idsrv.company.dev
- 192.168.1.101 dev.company.dev

.. and issued appropriate self-signed certificates so that the world was happy. Now I have a pucka wildcard certificate and have made the following changes:

- 192.168.1.100 idsrv_dev.company.co.uk
- 192.168.1.101 dev.company.co.uk

.. and I get the following error with Edge and IE when being redirected to the login page:

> **Error** There is an error determining which application you are signing into. Return to the application and try again.

Note: Works fine in Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the underscore "_" in the identity server address. Changing it to the following url fixed the problem:

- 192.168.1.100 idsrv-dev.company.co.uk